# how to replace value of env property in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm running a node project + reactjs on it. the process.env works inside the server.js but undefined in other js file.

I tried to build the project using webpack and then run the nodejs project like

here are the steps I did.

yarn build

CALLBACK_URL=https://localhost:9999/ BASE_URL=https://localhost:9443/ node server.js

I'm getting the log in server.js

process.env.BASE_URL https://localhost:9443/
process.env.CALLBACK_URL https://localhost:9999/

but I'm getting process.env.BASE_URL : undefined in other js file.

Comment: please past some code that you tried!

Answer (score 1):

Server.js is in the back end and is in scope of your "process" object.
React runs in the client browser engine. You need to get the environment variables From the "process" object available in your back-end's webpack build context into the webpack React Built files!

> See
>
> - [dotenv-webpack plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack)
> - [webpack-define plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/)
>
> for a possible elegant solution

Comment: I actually try this before, but what I wanted to do is to build the project once and run everywhere, so I needed to make the CALLBACK and BASE_URL passed from runtime and not in the compile time.

Comment: You do understand that accessing the server "environment variables" from a remote client running JS is impossible right? And it would actually be a disaster if this were possible. Your server should be the one to expose any variables like that. The client script cannot hack into the server and get those values.

Answer (score 0):

in webpack.config you can add these lines in plugins section:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env.CALLBACK_URL': 'https://localhost:9999/',
  'process.env.BASE_URL': 'https://localhost:9443/'
})
```